# out of bound exception in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginner to scala and what i'm doing is to map dataset into `(k, v)` pairs where `kv(0)` and `kv(1)` are Strings and `kv(2)` is a list. The code is listed below:

```
val rdd_q1_bs = rdd_business.map(lines => lines.split('^')).map(kv =>
  (kv(0), (kv(1), kv(2))))
```

But here's the problem, there are some empty lists for `kv(2)` in the dataset. So when I use `.collect()` to gather all the elements, there can be an out of bounds exception. 
What I'm thinking is to define a function and check the length of `kv`. Is there any simple way I can ignore the exception and keep the process, or replace `kv(2)` by a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines => lines.split('^')` function suggests that `rdd_business` rdd are all `RDD[String]` and you are splitting the strings with `^` which would give you `RDD[Array[String]]` and from that you are trying to extract the elements of Array using kv(0), kv(1) and kv(2). The exception you are getting is because there might be only one `^` in one of the `RDD[String]` (`rdd_business` object).

So what you can do in such case is to use `Try` or `Option`.

```
import scala.util.Try
val rdd_q1_bs = rdd_business.map(lines => lines.split('^')).map(kv =>
  (kv(0), (kv(1), Try(kv(2)) getOrElse("not found"))))
```

For better safety you can apply `Try` or `Option` on all the elements of the Array as

```
val rdd_q1_bs = rdd_business.map(lines => lines.split('^')).map(kv =>
  (Try(kv(0)) getOrElse("notFound"), (Try(kv(1)) getOrElse("notFound"), Try(kv(2)) getOrElse("not found"))))
```

You can proceed the same way for `Option` as well.

I hope the answer is helpful